# Excel vba: Getting range of cells on column B based on cell in column A

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have a vba script that gets info from all sheets, adds them to different comboboxes and whenever a value is selected from a combobox different things happens.
The first combo I populate as following:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim oCmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Set oCmbBox = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).cmbSheet
oCmbBox.Clear
For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If oSheet.Index > 1 Then
        oCmbBox.AddItem oSheet.Name
    End If
Next oSheet

End Sub
```

The second combobox is doing the following:

```
Private Sub cmbSheet_Change()

Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

'Report combo box
Dim oCmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Set oCmbBox = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).cmbSheet

'Tech combo box
Dim tCmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Set tCmbBox = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).techCombo
tCmbBox.Clear

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets(oCmbBox.Value).Range("A2:A10")
For Each cell In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        tCmbBox.AddItem cell.Value
    End If
Next cell

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).techCombo.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

I have a following sheet:
[image: sheet]

Now, selecting a value from techCombo (ie Teknik_1) I want the third combobox to be populated with data ranging from B6 - B9.
Is that possible??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try clicking on the combo box, then go into the Data tab >> Data Validation. Select List, and then set Data: to =$B$6:$B$9

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but thats not quite enough as I would like the values between B11 - B15 to be added to the combobox when Teknik_2 is chosen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your provided example data, something like this should work for you.  Note that this code is in the Sheet1 code module:

```
Private Sub techCombo_Change()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim cbo3 As ComboBox

    Set cbo3 = Me.ComboBox3 'Change to the actual name of the third combobox

    cbo3.Clear

    With Me.cmbSheet
        If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub    'Nothing selectd in cmbSheet
        Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(.Text)
    End With

    With Me.techCombo
        If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub    'Nothing selected in techCombo
        Set rFound = ws.Columns("A").Find(.Text, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
    End With

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        If Trim(Len(rFound.Offset(2, 1).Text)) = 0 Then
            cbo3.AddItem rFound.Offset(1, 1).Value
        Else
            cbo3.List = ws.Range(rFound.Offset(1, 1), rFound.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Private Sub ComboBox21_Change()
Dim TeckCMBxIndex
TeckCMBxIndex = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).ComboBox21.ListIndex
Select Case TeckCMBxIndex
    Case 0
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).ComboBox22.Clear
    Exit Sub
    Case 1
      Set rng = Worksheets("SHEET3").Range("B6:B10")
    Case 2
      Set rng = Worksheets("SHEET3").Range("B11:B15")
End Select
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(3).ComboBox22.Clear
For Each cell In rng
    If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
        ComboBox22.AddItem cell.Value
    End If
Next cell
End Sub`

Hope this should help you... I tried it and it worked form me. Note that i had the Values and comboboxes in sheet3.

Comment: ComboBox21 is your techCombo  and Combobox22 is your third combobox