# Excel vba: Getting range from a column with empty rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that I want to extract info from (with empty cells) based on a value from another column.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34747636/excel-vba-getting-range-of-cells-on-column-b-based-on-cell-in-column-a) helped me quite a lot with but I now have a column with multiple empty cells and the formula is not working...

[image]

**Code**:

```
Private Sub techCombo_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range

Dim cCmbBox As MSForms.ComboBox
Set cCmbBox = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).custCombo
cCmbBox.Clear

With Me.cmbSheet
    If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(.Text)
End With

With Me.techCombo
    If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Set rFound = ws.Columns("A").Find(.Text, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A"), xlValues, xlWhole)
End With

If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
    If Trim(Len(rFound.Offset(2, 1).Text)) = 0 Then
        cCmbBox.AddItem rFound.Offset(1, 1).Value
    Else
        cCmbBox.List = ws.Range(rFound.Offset(1, 1), rFound.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

An image showing an example:
So selecting VoLTE should populare a combobox with K1, K3, I7, U6
[image]

Comment: what's the expected result given the data you posted?

Comment: The comboBox is not populated as Set rFound is empty or rather when debugging the rFound is "Nothing". The expected result should be a ComboBox populated with Kund1-4

Comment: Are the rows that the values located on important?  For example, is it necessary to know that Kund1 is located on row 8?  If not, you can add piece of code to select the entire column and remove all duplicates which will remove the multitude of empty cells in the section of the column that has valid entries in it.

Comment: if rFound is nothing, then it's not finding the value in column A of your worksheet.  Can you confirm that Me.techCombo.Text is the value you're expecting AND it exists on your worksheet (no leading or trailing spaces, hidden non-printable characters, etc)?

Comment: @Brad you'll have to look in to his linked question to see how the data is laid out.  It's slightly more complicated than that.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Only way I know of is to search through a large enough collection of rows that it would be guaranteed that data wouldn't be missed.

Comment: Can you clean up the data, that would be the easiest thing.  Or, can you post a more comprehensive data list?

Comment: @sous2817 Yes Me.techCombo.Text value is in fact the value selected from the combobox nr 2. In this case it is VoLTE. What do you mean by cleaning up the data...The thing is that on right of kund1-4 column there will be information in cells in the spacing....I'll add a photo as soon as I get home.

Comment: Added an example image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```
If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
    If Trim(Len(rFound.Offset(2, 1).Text)) = 0 Then
        cCmbBox.AddItem rFound.Offset(1, 1).Value
    Else
        cCmbBox.List = ws.Range(rFound.Offset(1, 1), rFound.Offset(1, 1).End(xlDown)).Value
    End If
End If
```

with this:

```
If Not rfound Is Nothing Then
 LastRow = Ws.Cells(Ws.Rows.Count, rfound.Column + 1).End(xlUp).Row
 j = rfound.Row
 i = 1

 Do While j <= LastRow And rfound.Offset(i) = ""
  If rfound.Offset(i, 1) <> "" Then
   cCmbBox.AddItem rfound.Offset(i, 1)
  End If
  i = i + 1
  j = j + 1
 Loop
End If
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Had this been C# I would have done it in 5 mins :D

Comment: @Grendizer,You are welcome. if I need to do this in C# maybe I need 5 years :).