# Excel vba get value from cells based on multiple values from comboboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel document where I would like to extract values from cells based on multiple values based from comboboxes.

First combobox contains all values from column "Teknik".
Second combobox contains all values from column "Kund".
Third combobox contains all values from "year" row, 2016, 2017...
Forth combobox contains all the months Jan - Dec.

I would like to extract the values "Cust1" and "Demo" if I choose
VoLTE -> Kund1 -> 2016 -> Jan

[image]

```
Private Sub monthCombo_Change()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim yearFound As Range
Dim custFound As Range
Dim monFound As Range

'sheet
With Me.cmbSheet
    If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(.Text)
End With

'customer combo
With Me.custCombo
    If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Set custFound = ws.Columns("C").Find(.Text, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C"), xlValues, xlWhole)
End With

'year combo
With Me.yearCombo
    If .ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub
    Set yearFound = ws.Rows(3).Find(.Text, ws.Cells(3, ws.Columns.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
End With
End Sub
```

I was thinking that I should first find the customer, year and month, and then iterate thru the cells, but what I don't have a clue about in vba is how to tie all the variables together so that when choosing the above I get the right values.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34794436/excel-vba-getting-range-from-a-column-with-empty-rows/34797822) helped me with getting values connected to one value.

Comment: Spreadsheets don't really want to work this way.  You could try setting up a bunch of named ranges and then using offsets to get the values, but it would be a nightmare.  For example, there is no relationship between the column range 2016 and each month.  Lookup functions won't help you associate them.  The only way in Excel that I see a workable solution is to restructure the worksheet.

Comment: You can use match for the 1st and month and year, then loop for the kind column

Comment: Step1 to manipulating data in Excel [or anywhere, really]: make all of your input data as uniform as possible. Ideally, use everything with rows and tables, where each row has a unique ID which can be referred to specifically and link data tables together. And don't use merged cells. There is no point coding around inconsistent data formatting when you have the ability to make the data uniform in the first place.

Comment: I think what you seek is possible but will require very careful preparation. You have "VoLTE" in row 5. I assume somewhere below (row 50 say) there is another value in column A. So selecting "VoLTE" means selecting rows 5 to 49. For each value in column A, you must record the range of rows being selected. I assume "Kund1" is not unique. Is it unique within a column A value? For each value in column B, you must record the rows on which it appears. The intersection between the column A ranges and the column B rows gives you a row or a number of rows depending on how unique column B values are.

Comment: Selecting 2016 and "Jan" selects columns D to E. Selecting 2016 and "Feb" selects columns H to I. And so on. For each Month-Year you must record the columns it selects. So the first pair of combo boxes gives you a row or rows and the second pair gives you columns.  Together, they identify the values you want.

Comment: Thanks for all the input. Had this been C# this would have been much easier. I know the complex thing here is to keep track of the values, but what would be the better alternative and how should I restructure the worksheet?

Comment: If you know how to meet your requirement in C#, why not code it in C#?  The Net-Excel Interop may be slow but, as part of a user interface, I doubt that would be noticeable. You could load the entire worksheet to a 2D object array and handle everything within C#.

Comment: Cause C# is not an option right now :). So i wonder if there's an easier way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1):

I have not attempted to create any code that meets your requirements so this is a description of how I would develop that code.

It is not clear to me that tidying the worksheet would help.  I would start with what you have but reserve the right to tidy if I later thought it would help.

If you are not familiar with VBA, you may not be familiar with `ReDim`.  This statement is available with VB.Net but I know of no other language that includes it so I assume it is not available with C#.

```
Dim X(1 to 5) As String
```

The above defines a fixed size array of strings with elements 1 to 5.  VBA allows you to specify the lower bound of an array.  I assume C# does not.

```
Dim X() As String
```

The above specifies a dynamic array of strings that I will size, and perhaps resize, at runtime.

```
Dim X() As String
ReDim X(1 To 5)
ReDim X(1 To 10)
ReDim Preserve X(1 To 10)
```

- `Dim X() As String` defines X.
- `ReDim X(1 To 5)` sizes X to hold elements 1 to 5.
- `ReDim X(1 To 10)` releases the original X for garbage collection and creates a new X to hold elements 1 to 10.
- `ReDim Preserve X(1 To 10)` creates a new X to hold elements 1 to 10, copies values from the original X before releasing the original X for garbage collection.

You sometimes see `ReDim Preserve X(1 To UBound(X)+1)` within a loop when someone does not know in advance how big X needs to be.  You can imagine that this is very convenient but with a big enough loop it can become very slow and is generally not recommended.

I assume you do not have a large number of unique values so the slowing down will not matter too much so I would start with `ReDim Preserve X(1 To UBound(X)+1)` but be ready to try a different approach if this causes problems.

You say you have Combo Boxes.  A Combo Box allows the user to enter their own value if they do not like one of those offered.  This makes no sense in your scenerio.  You want List Boxes which are effectively the same as Combo Boxes without the user having the option to enter a value.

I would use Ranges, Unions of Ranges and Intersects of Ranges to control selection of the required cells.  Consider this demonstration macro:

```
Sub Demo()

  Const CellsPerSelection As Long = 2

  Dim RngColA As Range
  Dim RngColB As Range
  Dim RngYYMM As Range
  Dim RngSelected As Range
  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim Count As Long

  Set RngColA = Rows("5:49")
  Set RngColB = Union(Rows(8), Rows(40), Rows(55), Rows(80))
  Set RngYYMM = Union(Columns(5), Columns(6))

  Set RngSelected = Intersect(RngColA, RngColB, RngYYMM)

  If RngSelected Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "No intersect"
  Else
    Count = 0
    For Each Rng5 In RngSelected
      If Count = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Pair:";
      End If
      Debug.Print " " & Rng5.Address;
      Count = Count + 1
      If Count = CellsPerSelection Then
        Debug.Print
        Count = 0
      End If
    Next
  End If

End Sub
```

I don’t want to explain the VBA.  If you don’t understand a particular statement, you should be able to look it up easily enough. However come back with questions if necessary.  What I want to explain is the objectives of this code.

Consider: `Set RngColA = Rows("5:49")`.  In the real macro, I would have a list like this:

```
VoLTE     Rows("5:49")
XYZ       Rows("50:75")
UVW       Rows("76:100")
```

so the macro could convert the selection “VoLTE” into range `Rows("5:49")`.  Here I have just set RngColA to this range.

Consider `Set RngColB = Union(Rows(8), Rows(40), Rows(55), Rows(80))`.  Here I imagine the list as something like:

```
Kund1     Union(Rows(8), Rows(40), Rows(55), Rows(80))
Kund2     Union(Rows(9), Rows(35), Rows(65), Rows(95))
Kund3     Union(Rows(12), Rows(70), Rows(100), Rows(105))
```

The value against “Kund1” is the range created from the union of all the rows containing “Kund1” in column B.  Note, I have allowed for the value “Kund1” to appear twice within the “VoLTE”. I do not know if this is possible. If it is not possible, you can simplify the code at the end of the macro.

`Set RngYYMM = Union(Columns(5), Columns(6))` is similar but gives the columns for January 2016.

`Set RngSelected = Intersect(RngColA, RngColB, RngYYMM)` extracts the overlap between the selected ranges.  This overlap is `$E$8:$F$8,$E$40:$F$40`.  If there were only one value for “Kund1” this would be `$E$8:$F$8`.

The code at the bottom allows for there being no overlap.  If there is an overlap, it splits `RngSelected` into cell pairs.  I just output addresses to the Immediate Window but for you would use then to display values to the user.

Before you could use the equivalent of this macro to display value to the user, you would need to create the three lists from which values are selected.

For the first list, running down column A gives:

```
VoLTE     on row 5
XYZ       on row 50
UVW       on row 76
```

Separately, you would need to discover the last row with values is row 100.  This is all the information you need to create the list.

I would hold this list in an array.  Most languages offer Structures or Structs.  VBA calls them User Types but that is just a different name.  The definition must be at the top of the module:

```
Type ValueRange
  Value As String
  Rng As Range
End Type
```

The array definitions could be global would normally be within a sub routine:

```
Dim ColA() As ValueRange
Dim ColB() As ValueRange
Dim YYMM() As ValueRange
```

Hope the above helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explaining. I'll do my best to follow the above and will get back if questions arise.